# Sass library in Next JS

Tags: sass, next.js

My company use a Sass library that includes mixins and such. I have done an NPM install into my Next JS project.

My next.config.js file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
}
```

In _app.js I have `import '../styles/main.scss'`
What I don't understand is how do I get NextJS to include my library?

In other projects we would add an npm script "build:css": "npx fe-styleguide-build" but I want to benefit from Next JS hot reloading for seeing styling updates as soon as they are made.

Answer (score 2):

Next.js supports sass natively, all you have to do is `npm install sass` into your project and change .css to .scss, no need to tweak config file for that. With `npm dev` your sass will be compiled in real-time.

Comment: My question isn't about setting up and using Sass though, it's specifically about using a Sass library within a NextJS codebase

Answer (score 2):

You can import the styles directly from the *node_modules*. Import the file inside *pages/_app.js*, so that all other components can also access it:

```
// pages/_app.js
import 'your-library/dist/css/path-to-your-css.css'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Read more about it in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules).